# Add a css sub menu on a simple template menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a template with a simple menu inside the site, and I am a newbie with css.
I Want to add a sub menu just below the menu and a subsub menu on the right side 
of the sub menu.
Here is my html code:

```
<div class="site-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="UNNO.html"><span>A UNNO</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active"><span>Produtos</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Product 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Product 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Product 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Product 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Servicos.html"><span>Serviços</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS that belongs to the menu.

```
.site-nav {
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.site-nav ul {
  float: right;
  background-color: #1e1a18;
  height: 70px;
  border-top: 1px solid #221d19;
}

.site-nav ul li {
  font-size:1.08em;
  float:left;
  background:url(images/divider.gif) repeat-y right top;
  padding-right:2px;
}

.site-nav ul li a {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  background:url(images/nav-bg.gif) no-repeat 21px 32px;
  width:119px;
  height:70px;
}

.site-nav ul li a span {
  display:block;
  padding:26px 0 0 35px;
}

.site-nav ul li a:hover,
.site-nav ul li a.active {
  background-color:#ed1c24;
}

.site-nav ul li.twitter {
  background:none;
  padding:23px 0 0 0;
  border-right:1px solid #080808;
  text-align:center;
  width:102px;
}

.site-nav ul li.twitter a,
  .site-nav ul li.twitter a:hover {
  background:none;
}

.site-nav ul li.twitter a {
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: use a class like 'has-sub' on each parent li with sub item and cover all the sub-items with another ul and use css to hide them and show on hover

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="tabs"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="tabs"><a href="#">A UNNO</a></li>
        <li class="tabs"><a href="#">Produtos</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Product 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Product 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Product 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Product 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs"><a href="#">Servicos</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and use a `display: none;` to hide the submenus and only show them on hover.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nme9ktwa/2/)

Comment: Kalpetros, i replace the menu code in html, but i do not understand were it is suppose insert the display: none; on css. Change the code create 2 issues all menu disconfigured and the submenu does not appear. please help me!!!

Comment: Create the `.site-nav ul ul` selector in your css and add `display: none;`.

Comment: Hi Kalpetros! i create your example. site-nav ul ul {
 display: none;
} in CSS file.
yet no results on menu. e saw that you use li class tabs but were is it in css? please help!

Comment: Can you update the code you posted with your new code?

Comment: Hi guys ! Thanks to Kalpetros for the help!!! you helped me a lot, i have messed up all the code just to understand how it works and finnally i made it!!! thanks!!!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Don't forget to accept it as an answer.